# I want to display a list created by the user / React Native + Redux

Tags: android, ios, react-native, redux, react-redux

I want my apps to display what the user entered in the  tag under it with Redux.

So this is my container:

```
    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  text: state
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  addToList: () => { dispatch({ type: 'ADD_LIST' }) },
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodoList)
```

Here is my component:

```
class TodoList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          style={{height: 40, width: 300}}
          placeholder="Type here to translate!"
          onChangeText={(text) => this.props.text}
        />
        <Button
          title="Submit"
          onPress={this.props.addToList}/>
        <View>
          <Text>{this.props.text}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}



export default TodoList;
```

Here is the Store:

```
export const todoList = (state = [], action = {}) => {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'ADD_LIST':
    return [
        ...state,
        action.todo
    ];
  default:
    return state;
  }
}

let storeTodoList = createStore(todoList);

export default storeTodoList;
```

So i'm trying to get the text entered, add it to a list stored in the store and then display it, but i have absolutely no clue how to do this...

Comment: You're missing the payload in your call to `dispatch` in the container

Comment: I do not understand what's missing there. Sorry i'm a beginner in React native since i started today...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few things going on here...

1. Your `onChangeText` listener isn't doing anything. You need to capture the text entered into the component and send it to your dispatcher.
2. You need to include the new text passed in as part of your action creator.
3. `mapStateToProps` is responsible for taking the elements in application state and mapping it to the `props` to be made available to your component. For this example, your application state is pretty simple. It is just `{ text: 'SOME TEXT' }`.
4. You need to create a `Provider` for your Redux store. It should work at the root level of your app.

Here are all of the parts:

**App.js** (the application controller where the Provider is created)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import todoList from './actions/Reducer';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import Root from './Root';

class App extends Component {
  store = createStore(todoList);

  render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={this.store}>
          <Root/>
        </Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Root.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Button, Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    const displayText = this.props.textList.join();

    return (
        <View>
          <TextInput
              style={{height: 40, width: 300}}
              placeholder="Type here to translate!"
              onChangeText={(text) => this.props.updateField(text)}
          />
          <Button
              title="Submit"
              onPress={() => this.props.addToList(this.props.text)}/>
          <View>
            <Text>{displayText}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  text: state.textField,
  textList: state.list
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  updateField: (newText) => { dispatch({ type: 'FIELD_CHANGE', text: newText })},
  addToList: (text) => { dispatch({ type: 'ADD_LIST', text: text }) },
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Root)
```

**Reducer.js** (controls your state object)

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  textField: '',
  list: []
};

export default todoList = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action = {}) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FIELD_CHANGE':
      return {
        ...state,
        textField: action.text
      };
    case 'ADD_LIST':
      return {
        textField: '',
        list: [...state.list, action.text]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

EDIT-Changed example to add to a list. Note: **This is not the proper way to show a list of items in RN.** I'm just throwing the string into a `Text` field for the example. Use `FlatList` to properly show a list of items.

Comment: Sorry for the time i took to respond, this works just fine! I have one more question, how can i manage to store the value to a list when i click on submit, and then display it. I tried for several hours now but i still fail to make it work. Thank you for the time you took to help me :)

Comment: Updated example to append the field to a list when clicking on submit. Make sure to read my note on `FlatList`.

Comment: I thank you a loy for your time. I'll look further to make it work with FlatList. You made me understood a lot of things here !